# Disable Safari in OS X

Tags: macos, safari, internet, children

How do I disable Safari in OS X?

The desired effect is the same as in iOS: in iOS, you can easily disable Safari through the Restrictions settings, and the app just hides but is not uninstalled. You cannot search for the app, see an icon, or open it in any way.

I do not want to disable all browsers. In fact, that's the problem. The Parental Controls control all web things. And that's great. But if I want the default browser to be Google Chrome and I want to use a whitelist, then I can't use Parental Controls (at least since Yosemite). The Parental Controls option for a whitelist has been blocking everything from Chrome. Firefox has similar problems, but not as bad as with Chrome. If I use Chrome and Chrome's parental controls, then a user can just open Safari with no restrictions.

Comment: Why?  You've tagged "children": do you not want ANY browser enabled?  If so, you might make a proxy that leads all web pages to 127.0.0.1   This might have unintended consequences for other quasi-browser related activity, such as other apps that leverage Safari's HTML/CSS rendering, which may include Mail.app, etc..

Comment: @CharlesLindsay I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: As of OS X 10.11, you must [disable SIP](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11#) in order to do any of the solutions below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change permissions for Safari.

Open the information window on Safari (from the Finder window, with the Safari application selected, push <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or right-click), add the desired user, and set permissions to no access.

Comment: +1 This is probably a better idea because if you ever deleted Safari and needed to restore it without making a backup or deleting it caused unintended system problems, the only way to get it back would be to reinstall OS X.

Comment: Trying to find the "information window". `command`+`i` does nothing on the account I'm trying to set this up on. I might be doing it wrong, or it might not work from the controlled account, only from admin. I'll keep trying and bring back updates.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me find an "information window on safari". Can you give more information about that?

Comment: Go to the applications folder in finder, mark Safari and then hit cmd + i or right-click for information

Comment: Worked great. One note: when I added the user, I couldn't choose "No access", even if I was logged into the admin user when I tried to add the controlled user. However, it worked fine to leave the user off and mark "No access" for the "everyone" group. (All accounts use Chrome by default, so no big deal.)

Comment: @Joseph It's saying that I don't have the permission to choose "no access" for everyone.

Comment: @Airdish are you logged in as an admin account and did you unlock? (Small lock on the bottom of the window)

Comment: @KevinGrabher Yes I did. After doing so, I click on "Everyone" and try to change "custom" to "no access" but it says that I do not have the 'necessary permission'.

Comment: @Airdish With the update to OS X El Capitan, there are new security features that prevent users from tampering with System files. Not sure why they consider Safari a system file. But you have to disable the security if you have OS X El Capitan. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33640543/756329

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for the info. How will I know whether I have `/usr/local` ? And is it safe to disable the security? Is there any way to reenable it after I've disabled safari?

Comment: @Airdish In Terminal, you can type `ls /usr/local` and it will tell you if it exists. It is safe to disable security and then re-enable it. You should be able to find re-enable instructions in the link I posted, but the answer is simply: instead of the command `csrutil disable` you type `csrutil enable` when you're done.

Comment: @airdish I ran into a problem that looked like what you described, but I just had to click the lock button and it allowed me to change permissions.

Comment: `sudo chmod 770 /Applications/Safari.app` works for me

Answer (score 2):

Just open the terminal and type:

```
cd /Applications
sudo rm -R -f Safari.app
```

It will ask for your password and proceed to delete Safari from the system. You may want to backup the app before.

Comment: This may be what I end up doing, but it might have unintended consequences with other apps that access Safari stuff. (This happens on iOS: you can disable Safari and still open links in your email in the Google Inbox app, for instance. If you delete Safari, that would not be possible.)

Comment: I've used it like this for more than a month and no errors so far. Maybe I'm just being lucky haha.

Comment: That's useful information. I might do it, if no better options are found. You got my upvote!

Comment: This might not work on El Capitan because of rootless

Comment: You may wanna create a backup / change the location of the file instead of outright deleting it. Just changing the permission to ie 770 may still allow the system to update it